# Помогите с улучшением моего решения

Tags: python, оптимизация

```
Ограничение времени         1 секунда
Ограничение памяти  256Mb
```

> Андрей очень любит двоичные последовательности — последовательности,
> состоящие только из цифр 0 и 1. В особенности он любит
> последовательности, в которых цифры чередуются.
>
> Недавно Андрей придумал новое обозначение: sn — это двоичная
> последовательность длины n, в которой цифры чередуются, а первая цифра
> равна 0. Например, s6=010101, s3=010, а s1=0.
>
> Сегодня Андрею на глаза попалась двоичная последовательность t. Ему
> стало интересно, какова минимальная длина последовательности sm, для
> которой строка t является ее подпоследовательностью. Напомним, что b
> называется подпоследовательностью a, если из a можно вычеркнуть
> некоторые цифры, чтобы получилась последовательность b. Иными словами,
> Андрей хочет найти минимальное число m, для которого верно, что можно
> вычеркнуть из последовательности sm некоторые цифры, чтобы получилась
> последовательность t. Помогите Андрею справиться с этой непростой
> задачей 
> ***Формат ввода:*** 
> **Единственная строка входных данных содержит строку t, состоящую из
> нулей и единиц (1 ≤ |t| ≤ 105).**
>
> ***Формат вывода:***
>
> **Выведите минимальное число m, для которого верно, что t является
> подпоследовательностью sm.**

```
def isSubsequence(s, t):
        s = list(s)
        for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(t,s)):
            if a != b:
                s.insert(i,'.')
        return len(t) == len(s)
l = input() 
m = len(l)*2 
r = '01'*m 
m = len(r) 
while not isSubsequence(l, r):  
    r = r[:-1]  
    m -= 1 
print(m)
```

Мое решение слишком долгое и я не знаю как его оптимизировать.

Comment: А что у вас происходит в цикле while?

Comment: Отнимается последний символ у строки

Comment: А, понятно, строка сначала с запасом берётся.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать бинарный поиск по решению (конкретнее - поиск с[амого левого подходящего](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Procedure_for_finding_the_leftmost_element))

Для начала левая граница бинарного поиска `left =  len(l)`, правая `right = 2*len(l)`

Проверяете - выполняется ли для текущей длины (`mid=(left+right)/2`) isSubsequence.

Сложность получится O(nlogn).

Подозреваю, что может существовать линейное решение, но пока не увидел его.

Comment: немного не понял как можно это реализовать, можете ли привести пример кода?

Comment: У меня нет кода. Берете среднее значение mid между указанными left, right , и проверяете, подходит ли оно. Если нет - left устанавливаете в mid+1 и продолжаете. Если да, устанавливаете right в mid и продолжаете. Пока left и right не сойдутся. Ссылку на нужный вариант поиска я дал.

Comment: А если просто идти по исходной последовательности слева направо и вставлять нолики и единички там где их не хватает? Или я не понял условие задачи?

Comment: @GrAnd У меня была идея считать перевес единиц или нулей, но не додумал - похоже, в идеально простой форме это к вашему предложению и сведётся, если контраргументов не найдётся.

Answer (score 1):

Чего-то мне кажется, что надо просто пройти по исходной последовательности и "вставить" нужные цифры в тех местах, где их не хватает.

```
def calc(seq):
    i = 0
    for v in seq:
        i += 1 if i % 2 == int(v) else 2
    return i

print(calc('1100'))  # результат = 7
```

"Расшифровка" алгоритма.
`i` - позиция в выходной последовательности.
Берём цифру из исходной последовательности. Если она "правильная", то просто перемещаемся на следующую позицию `i += 1` (в обоих последовательностях). А если "не правильная", то в выходную последовательность виртуально добавляем правильную цифру и цифру из исходной последовательности, и, соответственно, в этом случае смещаемся на 2 позиции в выходной последовательности `i += 2`.

Comment: сложно понять смысл условия if i % 2 == int(v).

Comment: @xmikex На чётных позициях (0,2,4,6,...), где `i%2 = 0` - ожидается `0`, на нечётных (1,3,5,7,...), где `i%2 = 1` - ожидается `1`. Соответственно, если ожидание совпало с реальностью, то `i += 1`. Если нет, то `i += 2` (виртуальная вставка "нужной" цифры в выходную последовательность). Вообще, можно было ещё короче написать ту строчку - как `i += 1 + (i%2 != int(v))`. Но так будет совсем уж непонятно. :)

Answer (score 0):

Присваиваем начальное значение 1 длине подпоследовательности, потом если первый элемент равен 1, то увеличиваем на 1. Далее проходим до конца строки и при встрече t[i]!=t[i+1] увеличиваем на 1 значение длины, а при встрече t[i]=t[i+1] увеличиваем на два. Может тут ошибки, но вроде работает.

```
def subseqlen(t):
    result=1
    lent = len(t)
    if t[0]=='1':
        result += 1
    if (lent==1): return result
    for i in range (lent-1):
        if(t[i]!=t[i+1]):
            result += 1
        else:
            result +=2
    return result

t = str(input("Введите последовательность t: "))
print("Длина подпоследовательности равна %d"%subseqlen(t))
```